# Do Linux kernels have guard pages?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

I'm new to the Linux kernel, how does the Linux kernel memory management use guard pages (if this feature even exists)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Linux has guard pages.  The implementation in the latest Linux kernel recently changed somewhat in order to deal with a vulnerability ("stack clash") where the guard page can be skipped.  See this [post](https://www.qualys.com/2017/06/19/stack-clash/stack-clash.txt) for a description of the issue with the previous implementation.  See this [thread on LKML](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/6/22/345) for a discussion of recent changes.